# send string from C# app to php page

Tags: c#, php

i want send string to my php page and i used one of answers in this site

C# code:

```
 try
        {
            string url = "http://localhost:8080/test.php";
            string str = "test";
            HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            req.Method = "POST";
            string Data = "message=" + str;
            byte[] postBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Data);
            req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            req.ContentLength = postBytes.Length;
            Stream requestStream = req.GetRequestStream();
            requestStream.Write(postBytes, 0, postBytes.Length);
            requestStream.Close();

            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
            Stream resStream = response.GetResponseStream();

            var sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
            string responseText = sr.ReadToEnd();


        }
        catch (WebException)
        {

            MessageBox.Show("Please Check Your Internet Connection");
        }
```

and php code:

```
 if (isset($_POST['message']))
{
    $msg = $_POST['message'];
    echo $msg;
}
```

but its just a blank page.
can anybody tell me what is wrong????

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure setting "message=" + data will create an item in the post array called message: it may just create an unnammed item with content "message=blahblahblajh".
You can test this theory by doing this in your php:

```
foreach($_POST as $pdata)
echo " *-* ".  $pdata." *-*<br> ";
```

I've not used the HttpWebRequest for this, but you could try using the webclient class:

```
    string url = "http://localhost:8080/test.php";
    string str = "test";
    WebClient webClient = new WebClient();            
    NameValueCollection formData = new NameValueCollection();          
    formData["message"] = str;
    byte[] responseBytes = webClient.UploadValues(URL, "POST", formData);          
    string responsefromserver = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(responseBytes); 
Console.WriteLine(responsefromserver);          
    webClient.Dispose();
```

Alas, I'm not in a position to try this out at the moment, so this is from memory and google!

Comment: which library i should use for namevaluecllection??

Comment: System.Collections.Specialized

Comment: thank you for replying but its still just a blank page

Comment: strange, have you changed your php to echo all the contents of the $_POST array? Then at least you would see if anything is getting to PHP

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to the webpage from a browser after running the code, you would get a blank page, because your browser is not sending a post request, your application is, in order to view your response, just show the response text in a messagebox or a textbox. i.e.

```
MessageBox.Show(responseText);
```